# Office script, Delete range name ignored, no errors

Tags: excel, office-js, office-scripts

I just created this tiny Office script:

```
async function main(context: Excel.RequestContext) {
  context.workbook.names.getItem("Newname").delete;
}
```

The range name 'Newname' exists in the current workbook, the code runs without error but the name is not deleted. Why? I would expect to receive a runtime error if I'm not allowed to delete range names.

Answer (score 3):

I think it missed the bracket:

```
  context.workbook.names.getItem("Newname").delete();
```

I just tried by this gist, you could have a try. https://gist.github.com/lumine2008/f55a6265a93b421112de210b22e9a48a

Answer (score 3):

`delete` is a method. In JavaScript, a method requires opening and closing parentheses, even if there are no parameters to be passed:

```
context.workbook.names.getItem("Newname").delete();
```

My tests confirm this. Also, the code should include `await.context.sync();`

It's important to realize that JavaScript supports assigning a method to a variable (object), similar to assigning a function to an Excel `Name`, by leaving off the parentheses. This object can then be used at some point to execute the method. This is why no errors are thrown when the parentheses are omitted.

Example:

```
const deleteNewName = context.workbook.names.getItem("Newname").delete; 
deleteNewName();
```

(Thanks to Lumpenstein for this information about JS kindly provided in a comment.)